# Which technology to use to update thousands of elements in a view-port (like flightradar24.com) with good performance?

Tags: angular, reactjs, svg, canvas, real-time

We have a requirement to develop a real-time web application for airport surveillance.

The complexity is similar to that of flightradar24.com, where you can have thousands of objects that are updated in real time.

We tried using **SVG**, but its performance seems to decrease with increasing size.

Along with that, I tried using **React.js**. However, my state object is very large (a ~32MB nested JSON). This means updating state would be expensive as I would need to *deep clone* this object for every update.

I see that flightradar24 uses multiple small **canvas** elements. However, I couldn't figure out how are they rendered.

Any experience or tip for this kind of requirement would help a lot! Thank you.

Comment: flightradar24.com is developped using Angular JS and i think they are using WebSockets for real-time updates

Comment: Okay. Any idea regarding the seamless rendering of thousands of updates across multiple canvas elements?

Comment: I have done some application using Angular NgRX and SignalR. But as the objects to render increase browser seems to slower and it came to crash some points. I have been looking for the same how does other application developed but dont have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that specific example, but I've worked with webgl and [regl](http://regl.party) to animate > 250k points in a browser without any performance issues.  Here's the guide that pointed me in the right direction: https://bl.ocks.org/pbeshai/51d05995c5410a52116f89738144c622

Comment: Is there any provision to uniquely identify each of those points?

Comment: Yes, but the answer depends on if you're referring to the animation or for clicking on an item to get additional information.  For the animation you can position each dot individually and with Websockets pushing position changes in real time you could do create something similar to that website.  If you had a specific regl question I could help, but start with the regl examples.

Comment: (2/2) If you mean clicking on a dot and getting information about it, you can do that with a simple JS click event at the DOM level.  When a user clients on the DOM, it collects the X/Y coordinates of that click and then determines what object should be at that location.  If you're dealing with a lot of data it might be best to have it call a backend API to determine the correct objects.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I'll explore regl.